# When does the finish event get called in shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Using Shoes, I would like to have a block executed upon window destruction. I thought I could use the *finish* event, but in the following piece of code, "Starting" is displayed, but "Finished" is never shown.

---

```
Shoes.app(:title => "Test") do

    flow do
        start do |obj|
            alert("Starting")
        end

        finish do |obj|
            alert("Finished")
        end

        button "Hello"
    end
end
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some more researching...

It appears that the *finish* event in Shoes is currently only used for downloads.

In addition, it appears there is no *onclose* event currently, but it has been discussed.

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.shoes/2976

Apologies for answering my own question, but putting the knowledge out there for others.